# Why is my money disappearing in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Lately I have been playing Clash of Clans everyday.  I get on and my resources drop by 200,000. I look on the defense log and the attackers only steal 10-15,000 resources.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Look at the time stamps.  Are you sure you aren't being attacked multiple times?  In many cases, you can be attacked for less than 50% and lose tons of resources without getting a shield.  These attacks should all be listed on the screen when you load the game, but often times that screen bugs out and you don't actually see it.  Then the log is your only clue.

Comment: Are you spending all your elixir on troops?

Comment: Are you sure that nobody else had checked your base while you were away? (e.g. my little sister used to get on my phone and play, but since then I have added a passcode.

Answer (score 1):

It could just be a glitch. As CoC is a mainly server-based game, there are glitches and such. I would also change your password too, just to be safe, and then contact Supercell and submit a complaint.

It may just be a matter of deleting the game, logging out of game-center, re installing the game, and logging back into game-center. This worked when my game had glitches in the village loading, and it might work in this case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Erm.. What password? Clash of Clans uses device-based authentication tokens instead of a username and password. Your Game Center/Google Play accounts are just used to link several tokens together to load the same village.

Answer (score 0):

there is a glitch that hasn't been fixed yet where when you visit someone elses base you see the amount of resources you had before an upgrade or training troops. Is it possible that you upgraded something, visited someone else, then logged off?

Answer (score -1):

The only answer I can think of in the back of my head is that you're getting hacked. Change your password and make sure everything's safe. This also puts your GameCenter and Apple ID at risk (or if you're using Android, this puts your Google account at risk).